# j2me problem with using network objects

Tags: java, java-me, symbian, s60

I am trying to use j2me's IO package but whenever I try to create an object for example

```
DataInputStream is = null;
```

It shows me error stating

> DataInputStream cannot be resolved into a type

I even tried using InputStream as object but same error shows and when I use connector objects it doesn't show any error

I am using s60 v3 FP2 SDK

Please help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you import the `DataInputStream`.

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
```

If you're using and IDE it should tell you before you try to compile that it can't find `DataInputStream`, and a good IDE will give you the option to resolve the import for you.